# how to add the "alt" attribute to a "managed_file" type image field

Tags: forms, files

I have a custom form in drupal 9 where I am creating a managed_file type field to upload an image:

```
$form['footer']['logo'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Logo',
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['png jpg jpeg'],
  ],
  '#description' => t('The valid formats are png, jpg, jpeg'),
  '#default_value' => $data['footer']['logo'] ?? '',
);
```

And I need to add the "alt" attribute to the field and the user can add this information when uploading the image, however when I make the attempt to add it normally it doesn't work:

```
$form['footer']['logo'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Logo',
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#alt' => 'Example'
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['png jpg jpeg'],
  ],
  '#description' => t('The valid formats are png, jpg, jpeg'),
  '#default_value' => $data['footer']['logo'] ?? '',
);
```

can anyone give me an idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Managed file elements don’t have an alt (that’s an image field, different thing altogether). Add a separate text field for alt, and save/load its data alongside the file ID when you need to

Comment: Okay and maybe it would be easier to use a field of type "image" or something like that instead of using "managed_file"?

Comment: Field widgets only work with entities, for manual forms you need to build it yourself