# How to add a description(alternate text) for a custom file field created

Tags: forms

I have to a description text field a file field created in form alter

```
$form['test_file'] = [
          '#type' => 'managed_file',
          '#title' => t('File Upload'),
          '#upload_location' => 'public://test/',
          '#upload_validators' => array(
              'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx txt'),
            ),
];
```

Comment: Please refer this link for solution:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316153/how-to-add-the-alt-attribute-to-a-managed-file-type-image-field